# Docker build with Jenkins issue

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, docker-build, jenkins-docker

I am trying to write a Jenkins pipeline which first clones a git repository, then builds a Docker image and finally pushes the image to the Docker Hub. My `Jenkinsfile` is:

```
pipeline {
    agent { dockerfile true }
    environment {
        APPLICATION = 'connect'
        ENVIRONMENT = 'dev'
        BUILD_VERSION = '0.9.5'
        MAINTAINER_NAME = 'Shoaib'
        MAINTAINER_EMAIL = 'shoaib@email.com'
        BUILD_DOCKER_REPO = repo1/images'
        DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG = 'repo1/images:connect_dev_0.9.5'
    }
    stages {
        stage('clone repository') {
            steps {
                checkout Jenkins-Integration
            }
        }
        stage('Build Image') {
            steps {
                image = docker.build("-f Dockerfile.local", "--no-cache", "-t ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}", "--build-arg envior=${ENVIRONMENT} .", "--build-arg build_version=${BUILD_VERSION} .", "--build-arg maintainer_name=${MAINTAINER_NAME} .", "--build-arg maintainaer_email=${MAINTAINER_EMAIL} .")
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.example.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
                        image.push(${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG})
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run this job (in Blue Ocean) I am getting the following error:

[image]

I have tried googling it, but could not find a satisfactory answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: remove all `.` at the end of each `--build-arg key=value`, except the last `--build-arg ...`

Comment: tried it @yong but same response "WorkflowScript: 20: Expected a step @ line 20, column 17."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `docker.build` in below stage into a `script` as following:

```
stage('Build Image') {
    steps {
        script {
            def image = docker.build(
                "-f Dockerfile.local", 
                "--no-cache", 
                "-t ${DOCKER_IMAGE_TAG}", 
                "--build-arg envior=${ENVIRONMENT}", 
                "--build-arg build_version=${BUILD_VERSION}", 
                "--build-arg maintainer_name=${MAINTAINER_NAME}", 
                "--build-arg maintainaer_email=${MAINTAINER_EMAIL} .")
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, its working now, another question, is ${ENVIRONMENT} correct way to access vairables declared in environment?

Comment: Fine, it works, but please, do not copy the `--no-cache` without a very good and usually very temporary reason (like breaking a stale cached image resisting desired change), as in most circumstances it just wastes CPU cycles and energy (see also the DRY principle).